# Why is intensity related to number of photons?

Tags: optics, statistical-mechanics, spectroscopy

I have been reading up on Doppler broadening and have found a number of sources (for example [here](http://www.pci.tu-bs.de/aggericke/PC4e_osv/Spectroscopy050119/node8.html) and [here](http://physics.csustan.edu/Ian/Spectroscopy/LectureNotes/Broadening.pdf)) which seem to be taking the number of photons in the range $[\nu,\nu+d\nu]$ to be the same distribution (Gaussian) as the power spectrum at that point. I cannot see how this can be true, since surly to get power from number of photons you need to times by $\nu$ meaning they won't have the same distribution. Please can someone shed some light on this for me?

Comment: Physical detectors measure photon flux (that's why intensity is $\propto |\psi|^2$ in QM and $\propto |\vec{E}|^2$ in classical electrodynamics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite right that the the power in the range $\nu$ to $\nu + d\nu$ should be done by having a term something like $n(\nu)\;h\nu$.

However because the change in wavelength (frequency) is very small as shown in one of your links, FWHM = 0.024 nm for a central wavelength of 388.9 nm, the assumption is made that $h\nu \approx h \nu_o$, ie all the photons have approximately the same energy.  Thus the intensity is proportional to the number of photons arriving per second.